# Is my proof that this limit does not exist correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Proposition:

Let $f$ be a function defined as $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches any number $a \neq 0$ does not exist.

My proof:

Suppose by contradiction that there is a limit $L$ for $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a \neq 0$.
By definition of limit, there is a $\delta$-neighborhood of $a$ in which, as $x$ gets closer to $a$, in a $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $L$, $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$.
Let's take a irrational number $x$ in such an neighborhood of $a$. That would imply $|L| < \epsilon$. 
We know that we can find a $y$ even closer to $a$ which implies that $f(y)$ is even closer to $L$ than $f(x)$ was. 
Since there are infinitely many numbers like that who happen to be rational, we have that $|y - L| < |L|$. 
But we also have infinitely many irrational numbers $z$, that are even closer to $a$ such that $f(z)$ is closer to $L$ than $f(y)$ was. 
So we must have $|L| < |y - L| < |L|$ which is absurd. 
We conclude then that there is no limit $L$. ■

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your proof entirely. you're using vague notions like "getting closer", and your logic is a bit wacky.

You want to disprove that there is a limit at $a$. The definition of limit at $a$ is

> $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists $\iff$ there exists an $L$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

If you want to disprove this, then you have to prove the negation. We get:

> $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't exist $\iff$ for any $L$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $\delta > 0$ there is an $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$ such that $|f(x) - L|\geq \epsilon$

Wow, that's a mouthful. However, the key part here is this: "there exists an $\epsilon >0$". You have to show that some $\epsilon$ exists. The easiest way of doing that is to pick one (cleverly), and then use that. Once I saw that you hadn't done that, I was almost certain that your proof wouldn't be correct.

For instance, a proof might go like this:

---

Let $L$ be arbitrary. Set $\epsilon = \frac{|a|}3$. Let $\delta$ be arbitrary. Now pick a rational $x_1$ and irrational $x_2$ such that $0<|x_i-a|<\delta$ for $i = 1, 2$ and at the same time $|x_1|>\frac23|a|$. (For small $\delta$'s this last condition won't matter, as $|x_1-a|<\delta$ is a strictly stronger condidion, but one has to take into account that a devil's advocate might pick our arbitrary $\delta$ to be larger than $\frac13|a|$.) I will now show that $|f(x_1) - L|<\epsilon$ and $|f(x_2) - L|<\epsilon$ cannot both hold (and thus one of them must be $\!{}\geq\epsilon$).

Assume for contradiction that $|f(x_1) - L|<\epsilon$ and $|f(x_2) - L|<\epsilon$. We know that $x_2$ is irrational, which gives us $|L|<\frac{|a|}3$. We know that $x_1$ is rational, giving us $|x_1-L|<\frac{|a|}3$. Thus
$$
|x_1 - L| + |L| < \frac23|a|\\
|x_1 - L + L| < \frac23|a|\\
|x_1| < \frac23|a|
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: But why  $|x_1|>\frac23|a|$?

Comment: @ArielK Because we need it for the contradiction later.

Comment: @ArielK I'm not saying $|x_1| = \frac23|a|$. I'm saying $|x_1|> \frac23 |a|$. Regardless of whehter $a$ is rational or not, there are plenty of rational numbers to choose from for $x_1$.

Comment: Thanks, just realized that :P sorry for my stupidity

Comment: @ArielK  These proofs are often thought through before the final version is written down. Things need constant tweaking as you figure out what you need. For instance, I started with $\epsilon = \frac{|a|}2$, and then thought "but what if $x_1$ is chosen to be smaller than $a$?", so I changed it to $\frac{|a|}3$. Then I thought "What if $\delta$ is really large, and $x_1$ is chosen to be really close to $0$?", so I made the requirement that $|x_1|>\frac23|a|$. Maybe I could've saved myself all the trouble and just required that $|x_1|>|a|$ in the first place. The proof might've been neater.

Comment: ... But I didn't think of that until just now, so I'm stuck with what you see here.

Comment: This all, including comments, illustrates nicely the thinking of a mathematician.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not acceptable.

E.g. you use terminology like "closer" or "getting closer" without making clear what is meant by that. This makes it impossible to check your proof.

---

Observe that $\mathbb Q^{\complement}$ and $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ are both dense subsets of $\mathbb R$.

From that conclude that there are a sequences $(p_n)_n$ and $(q_n)_n$ both converging to $a$ with $p_n\in\mathbb Q^{\complement}$ and $q_n\in\mathbb Q$ for every $n$.

If a limit $L$ exists then $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(p_n)=a$ and $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=0$ which is not possible if $a\neq0$.

Comment: Why should "$y$ even closer to $a$ than $x$" **imply** that "$f(y)$ is even closer to $L$" than $f(x)$"? Such $y$ will exist, but must be chosen. It is not enough to let it  rest only on the (vague) fact that $y$ is closer to $a$. Further to judge informal arguments is more difficult for me than to judge formal proofs.

Comment: Because the definition of limit implies that there is such an neighborhood of a for which we can make f(x) as close as we wish from the limit by taking sufficiently closer to a

Comment: Yes, and the condition must be that $y$ belongs to such neighborhood. Not only that $y$ is closer to $a$ than $x$. That is not enough on its own.

Comment: But I stated that $y$ not only is closer but is also in that neighborhood, how could it be out of the neighborhood if it's closer to $a$ than $x$?

Comment: Where did you state that $y$ is in that neighborhood? I do not encounter that. Only that $x$ and $y$ are in some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $L$ and that $y$ ix closer to $a$ than $x$. Again: that is not enough to ensure that $f(y)$ is closer to $L$.